# "spawn id exp5 not open" Error when when scp'ing with an expect script

Tags: expect, scp, spawn

I have the an expect script that starts like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 1200
set prompt {[#$] }

set server [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set package [lindex $argv 3]

spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$package" ${username}@${server}:~

expect {
    timeout { send_user "\nscp connect time out\n"; exit 1 }
    "*assword"
}

after 3000

send "$password\r"

# wait for upload complete

expect {
    timeout { send_user "\nscp timeout\n"; exit 1 }
    eof
    }

....
close
```

It errors out with the following message after ~15 s:

```
send: spawn id exp5 not open
        while executing
    "send "$password\r""
```

What could be the reason for this? What does exp5 mean?
I have also tried removing the "after 3000" statement, but I get the same error.

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is closed by the time you get to the point where you send your password. I suspect that you don't need to enter a password for that server (ssh keys are set up?), and by the time 3 seconds has elapsed (`after 3000`), the file transfer is complete.

You can condense your script somewhat:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 1200
set prompt {[#$] }

lassign $argv server username password package
# if your expect version does not have `lassign`, stick to below
#set server [lindex $argv 0]
#set username [lindex $argv 1]
#set password [lindex $argv 2]
#set package [lindex $argv 3]

spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$package" ${username}@${server}:~

expect {
    timeout    {send_user "\nscp time out\n"; exit 1}
    "*assword" {send "$password\r"; exp_continue }
    eof
}
```

This loses the distinction between connection timeout and transfer timeout though.